# Check value from another table and based on the value save in current

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to check what value has column in another table and based on that value to save in current table. Here is the controller so you can get what I mean

```
$preference = Preferences::pluck('preferences_is_active');

    $book = new book;
    $book->book_description = Input::get('description');
    $book->book_title = Input::get('title');
    $book->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    if($preference !== 1) {
        $book->book_published = 0;  
        $book->save();
    }
return Redirect::to('/users/books');
```

So I want user to be able to save new books' information in his profile. But also want to check column `preferences_is_active` in table `preferences` and do the conditions.

The problem is that no matter what value has `preferences_is_active` it's always saves `0` in `books` table. What I miss here?

Comment: $preference = Preferences::pluck('preferences_is_active'); retrieve a collection of column. For this when you check it does not work

Comment: Does book_published have a default value of 0? Preferences::pluck should return a collection of items and not a singular item.

Comment: book_published has default 1

Comment: Actually which field you want to check that it is 1 or 0? Unless you wont able to check it.

Comment: I want to check the value in `Preferences` and if is not `1` save `0` in Book table `$book->book_published = 0` if is `1` must leave it to default value of `$book->book_published`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `pluck` will return acollection, so you can do it like this :

```
$preference = Preferences::first();

$book = new book;
$book->book_description = Input::get('description');
$book->book_title = Input::get('title');
$book->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

$book->book_published = $preference->preferences_is_active;

$book->save();
return Redirect::to('/users/books');
```

Comment: preferences table may contain more then one row.

Comment: @MahfuzShishir I don't think so because with his logic, he expect one result :p

Comment: @Ivan is it the case?

Comment: I understand that. But he does not mention it clearly. :-P

Comment: preferences has more columns and with pluck I want to take only that one

Comment: There is no problem if it's more columns, is there more than one row in the preferences table ??

Comment: Yes, it is only one row. Tried your solution but got `Undefined variable: {"preferences_id":1,.....}` it's showing all columns from preferences

Comment: Where you get this error? and ave you a column named `preferences_is_active` ?

Comment: I get this on `Submit` button and yes eg. on save, I have that column

Comment: Add `dd('saved');` before `return Redirect::to('/users/books');` and try again, what did you get  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158003/discussion-between-maraboc-and-ivan).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
$preference = Preferences::first();

$book = new book;
$book->book_description = Input::get('description');
$book->book_title = Input::get('title');
$book->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

if(!$preference) {
    $book->book_published = 0;  
    $book->save();
}
return Redirect::to('/users/books');
```

Comment: How will know which column from Preference to check?

Comment: It is only one row